# Getting exception FontFormatException Unsupported sfnt resources/fonts/OpenSansEmoji.ttf

Tags: java, fonts, emoji, truetype, opentype

I have OpenSansEmoji.ttf and another fonts like Proxima Nova Regular.otf in the resources/fonts folder,for Proxima Nova Regular.otf / Proxima Nova Alt Light.ttf it is not giving me exception and neither for OpenSansEmoji.otf but for OpenSansEmoji.ttf it is giving me following exception what should I do?

```
 Feb  25, 2015 10:37:31 AM java2d.utils.FontUtils getFont
    SEVERE: null
    java.awt.FontFormatException: Unsupported sfnt resources/fonts/OpenSansEmoji.ttf
        at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.init(TrueTypeFont.java:522)
        at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.<init>(TrueTypeFont.java:191)
        at sun.font.SunFontManager.createFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2460)
        at java.awt.Font.<init>(Font.java:614)
        at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:1023)
        at java2d.utils.FontUtils.getFont(FontUtils.java:53)
        at java2d.CrushCard.drawMessageString(CrushCard.java:311)
        at java2d.CrushCard.createCrushCard(CrushCard.java:134)
        at java2d.Java2D.main(Java2D.java:43)
```

My code is here

```
  try {
            FontUtils.registerFonts(fonts);
        } catch (IOException | FontFormatException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Java2D.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



  public static void registerFonts(List<String> paths) throws IOException, FontFormatException {

        for (String path : paths) {
            String fName = "resources/fonts/" + path;
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(fName)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: registerFonts doesn't show up in your stack trace?!

Comment: @Adrian Leonhard Java2D.java:43 jumps to this line in code=>   FontUtils.registerFonts(fonts);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFNT is a container format for fonts, used by TrueType among others. However, Java doesn't support all SFNT fonts, only TrueType.

From the sun.font.TrueTypeFont javadoc:

> TrueTypeFont is not called SFntFont because it is not expected to handle all types that may be housed in a such a font file.

Basically this means that your font, while having a .ttf file ending, isn't actually TrueType and you can't use it. It could be that it is an OpenTypeFont, which isn't supported by Java. You could try converting the font; google shows a number of possibilites.

Comment: thanks for you immediate response by converting the font to true type font online it is not giving me exception now :)